# Barcode integration for crystal report CRforVS_13_0_8 code39 or code128

Tags: crystal-reports, report, barcode, code128

I am trying to add Barcode in my crystal report.I need free service not paid.I have tried azalea bar code implementation.

I have added azalea code 129 function in formula field and  create a new formula field with name code128 and i placed in my crystal report.i have also downloaded code128 Font from 3rd party site i set the font also, when i generate the report the barcode was not readable.

I am looking for a complete kit of barcode integration for crystal report for free or any other solution.

Requirement :

Need to generate Alphanumeric barcode in crystal report.

Thanks in advance. Need help........

Comment: what is Azalea code 129? I can't find anything about that on google?

Comment: http://azalea.com/ In crystal report additional fuction there is azalea(u25azalea.dll) in that BarcodeC128A avilable.

Comment: Post a photo of the bar code.

Comment: i followed this guide : http://www.azalea.com/crystal-reports-custom-functions/code-39/

Comment: i want to know is barcode is freely available for crystal report ????

Comment: Finally i got barcode implementation @ crystal report. Link http://www.idautomation.com/free-barcode-products/code39-font/#Bar_Code_Font

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i got barcode implementation @ crystal report. http://www.idautomation.com/free-barcode-products/code39-font/#Bar_Code_Font

Answer (score 0):

You can also use online barcode generator services. Create a hyperlink where the barcode alphanumeric is part of the URL to generate your barcode dynamically per barcode. This requires internet access. Code 3 of 9 is inefficient and takes a lot of space to generate a barcode. Code 128 is more compact and can generate alphanumeric easily.